# Cypress, how to upload a file on pop-up and the type=button

Tags: file, upload, popup, cypress

What should I do, if I want to upload a file, when the `type=button` and this button on a pop-up? Even using the xpath find by cypress helper, I can't upload a file:

```
cy.contains('点击上传').attachFile(filename,{ force: true })
cy.get('.el-upload > .el-button > span').attachFile(filename)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding invoke('show') and trigger:

cy.get('input[type="file"]').invoke('show');
cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile(fileName).trigger('input');